# TypeScript: force interface to have all of the indexes of union type

Tags: typescript

I have union like:

```js
type A = "a" | "b" | "c";
```

And I would like to have an interface like:

```js
interface B {
  [index: A]: string
}
```

But I would want this interface to force to have **all** of the options of union type, so the final interface would look like this:

```js
interface B {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using mapped type:

```js
type B = {
  [K in A]: string
};
```